# Is there an Auth Component's helper in Cakephp 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Is there an Auth Component's helper in Cakephp 2.x?**
Currently I just pass the $Auth object to the view in the AppController like so:

```
$this->set('Auth', $this->Auth);
```

I searched around but there doesnt seem to be a helper available by default. I need some of the functions of the Auth component in the views like Auth::loggedIn().

help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There is no need for an AuthHelper

The [AuthComponent::user](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L584) function can be called statically:

```
if (AuthComponent::user()) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

Or since it [just reads from the session](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L596) the same information can also be found via the session (component/helper/class):

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

It is not a good idea, or required to pass the Auth component (or any component) to the view.

Comment: But if i were to call the component from the view, even if it were a static call, wouldnt it still defeat the purpose / good practice of not using components in the views. The Session->read() seems to be a bit cumbersome dont you think? is there no other alternative? Maybe i should write up a small Helper class myself?

Comment: no, no, don't think so (why do you need an alternative?) and that helper _is_ the session helper - or: what is it going to do that you can't _already_ do just as easily?

Comment: for easier access? with some helper magic i could turn `$this->Session->read('Auth.User')` into `$this->Auth->loggedIn()` which i think is more clearer. If i am using a helper, whats the harm?

Comment: There's no harm it's just a waste of effort :). But if it works for you - sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Auth Component still exists: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Comment: The component is there. But i want to access some of the methods of the component in the View. We cant really access components in the view. so i was wondering whether there would be a helper, like the SessionHelper